# Counterexample for uniform integrability of a stopped process

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stopping-times, uniform-integrability

I want to find an example where $X_n$ is uniformly integrable, $N$ is a stopping time, but $X_n^N = X_{\min\{n,N\}}$ in not uniformly integrable.

There is a theorem saying that if $M_n$ is a uniform integrable martingale, $N$ is a stopping time, then $M_n^N = M_{\min\{n,N\}}$ in also a uniform integrable martingale. So, what I know at least is that $X_n$ cannot be a martingale. Any suggestion?

Comment: **Observation:** If $\Bbb P[N<\infty]=1$ and $X_N$ is integrable, then $X^N_n$ will be uniformly integrable, because
$$
|X_n^N|\le |X_N|+|X_n|\cdot1_{\{N\ge n\}}.
$$
So your example must have $\Bbb E|X_N|=\infty$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins good observation. But still cannot find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example:** Let $\{X_n\}$ be i.i.d. with the unit rate exponential distribution on $[0,\infty)$. This is a uniformly integrable sequence because each $X_n$ is integrable and they all have the same distribution. Let $Y$ be a positive random variable independent of $\{X_n\}$ with $\Bbb E[Y]=\infty$. Let $\mathcal F_n:=\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n,Y)$ and define an $\{\mathcal F_n\}$ stopping time $N$ by $N:=\inf\{n:X_n\ge Y\}$. Then $\Bbb P[N<\infty]=1$ and $\Bbb E[X_N]\ge\Bbb E[Y]=\infty$, so $\{X^N_n\}$ cannot be uniformly integrable.

Comment: Interesting example. The only part about which I am not sure is your claim that $P[N<\infty] =1$.

Comment: For fixed $y>0$, $\Bbb P[X_n\ge y$, i.o.$]=1$ by Borel-Cantelli, so $\Bbb P[X_n\ge Y$, i.o. $]=1$ by Fubini's theorem.