# Stopped process not uniformly integrable

Tags: martingales, stopping-times, uniform-integrability

I need to construct a counter example such that the process $\{X_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ is uniformly integrable; however, the stopped process $X_{\tau \wedge n}$ where $\tau$ is a stopping time, is NOT uniformly integrable. I thought it will be easier to consider these two cases: 1. $X_n$ be a martingale; 2. $\mathbb{E}[\tau] = \infty$; However the example does not need to meet neither of 1 and 2. Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate; answered with an example by @John Dawkins at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1732198/counterexample-for-uniform-integrability-of-a-stopped-process?